# Why my ubuntu is showing as if I am connected to a battery power source?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop

I am not connected to any batteries but still ubuntu says I am connected to batteries and shows time remaining..

[image]

Comment: if it is a new installation it might be calibrating. Otherwise it might also be a hardware problem. `cat /sys/class/power_supply/ADP1/online`  will show a 1 when on battery and 0 when not. The power cord might be damaged or not correctly connected. My system shows "fully charged" and not a time ;-)

Comment: Are you connected to an uninterrupted power supply (UPS)?